# IoT Data integration with IBM maximo

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud, data-import, ibm-maximo-worker-insights

I am new to IBM maximo, I tried searching for documentation to integrate by IoT data available in my database server with asset management module of IBM maximo.
There are data import and REST API options available as per some experts, but I am not able to find specific documentation regarding how to use it.
Can someone please help me providing some details on it?